# Keep tracks on e-mails

Tags: iphone, email, mfmailcomposer

For technical reasons, I'm not using the `MFMailComposer` to send a mail to some users, but my own web service. Doing this does not leave a track of the sent e-mail to my outbox. Is there a way to place a copy of my message in the outbox programmatically??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you won't be able to artificially insert something in the "Sent Mail" folder (I assume that's what you meant instead of Outbox).  This is because MFMailComposer is just a view of the mail client and the Sent Mail folder reflects what is actually sent via your email provider.

Comment: Yes I meant the 'Sent Mail' folder, my mistake :). Thanks for your answer.